# Bind a textblock in a nested list member

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have these classes:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string id{get;set}
    public List<Brewery> breweries { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
public class Brewery
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
```

And this Listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="580" Margin="0,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem Tap="ListBoxItem_Tap" Tag="{Binding Path=id}">                 
                       <TextBlock Name="First"  Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                       <TextBlock Name="Second" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=breweries.name}" />
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So I create a list of Datum objects and I bind the listbox to it. In that way, the First textblock is bound to the property 'name' of the Datum class.That works perfectly. What I want is the Second textblock to be bound to the property 'name', of the first item of the Brewery list. 
If breweries was not a List I would easily do that, but since I take the info from a json, I can't change that.

Comment: Where is the textbox? In the list? Outside? Does it fill based on currently selected item in the list?

Comment: Yes its in the list. The list is bound to a Datum list and I want this particular textblock to be bound to the property 'name' of the nested Brewery list of the class

Comment: Which item of the nested Brewery list do you want to bind it to?!

Comment: Can you show us the current code that isn't working?

Comment: I updated the post, I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, if I understand what you're doing correctly, you should just be able to use an index to bind to the desired item from the collection. I'm not sure it's the best approach, but it should yield the result you're after.

E.g. (adapting your example):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="580" Margin="0,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBoxItem Tap="ListBoxItem_Tap" Tag="{Binding Path=id}">                 
                       <TextBlock Name="First"  Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
                       <TextBlock Name="Second" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=breweries[0].name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That did work fine. 

Thanks :D

The odd thing is that the json returns an array while there's no reason to, since the list always contains 1 object. So the [0] isn't conflicting with any result

Comment: How odd, could be potentially something to take care of when building the object (if you know there's only going to be one), just to save you having to work around it. Good luck =D